# How can I run an application full screen on a second screen?

Tags: snow-leopard, screen, fullscreen

I want to run games on my additional screen, how can I do this? By default they run on the  built-it screen.

I'm using a MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real FullScreen applications will normally run on the Primary Display and they will rarely allow you to configure that. Some applications, however, are running in a “false” full screen, and are just “maximized” applications on top of everything, including the dock and the MenuBar. Some of the latter can be moved by applications like SizeUp and similar (*note the usage of the word ‘some’*).

In order to change what your primary display is, you have to go to System Preferences -> Display and the click on the “Arrangement” Tab. And then you have to click and drag the white menubar to the display you want to make primary. Take a look at the attached picture. Remember you have to click on the white square representing the Menu Bar and *drag* it to the other.

[image: Display Preference Pane]

The consequences of doing that is that your Dock and your Menu Bar will be moved onto the other Display.

Answer (score 1):

use your external monitor as main

apple-> system Preferences-> Displays

Make sure red border pointed to external monitor

and you should good to go:)